# How to avoid duplicate code including std::map and std::mutex

Tags: c++

I have a class including a map, and a mutex. In every member function the mutex protects the map from multiple thread accessing the object of this class, for ex:

```
class bar
{
public:
    void hello() {}
    void set_something(int x) {}
    int get_something(int x, int y) { return x + y; }
};

class foo
{
public:
    foo()
    {
        m_map[0];
        m_map[1];
        m_map[2];
    }
    void hello(unsigned int index)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mut);
        const auto iter = m_map.find(index);
        if (iter != m_map.end())
            iter->second.hello();
    }
    void set_something(unsigned int index, int x)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mut);
        const auto iter = m_map.find(index);
        if (iter != m_map.end())
            iter->second.set_something(x);
    }
    int get_something(unsigned int index, int x, int y)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mut);
        const auto iter = m_map.find(index);
        if (iter != m_map.end())
            return iter->second.get_something(x, y);
        return 0;
    }
private:
    std::mutex                  m_mut;
    std::map<unsigned int, bar> m_map;
};
```

Is there an elegant method to avoid duplicate code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a proxy and RAII like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <map>

template < typename F, typename S> 
struct mutex_map {
    std::recursive_mutex m_;
    std::map<F,S> map_;

    struct Proxy {
        Proxy( std::map<F,S> & map, std::recursive_mutex &m ) : map_(&map), lock_(m) {
            std::cout << "lock\n";
        }
        ~Proxy() { std::cout << "unlock\n"; }
        std::map<F,S>* map_;
        std::unique_lock<std::recursive_mutex> lock_;

        std::map<F,S>* operator->() { return map_; }
    };

    Proxy operator->() {
        return { map_, m_ };
    }
};

int main() {
    mutex_map<int, int> mm;

    mm->emplace(1, 3);
    std::cout << (mm->find(1) == mm->end()) << "\n";
    std::cout << (mm->find(2) == mm->end()) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Using Proxy Pattern for this is awesome! Does it also work if my example use std::shared_mutex instead of std::mutex?

Answer (score 2):

You can move common part into "do_something" and pass functor into it:

```
...
void do_something(const std::function<void(bar&)>& func)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mut);
    const auto iter = m_map.find(index);
    if (iter != m_map.end())
        func(std::ref(*iter));
}

int get_something(unsigned int index, int x, int y)
{
    do_something(std::bind(&bar::get_something, std::placeholders::_1, index, x, y));
}
...
```

One question - do you need to protect with mutex only std::map or std::map and its elements? You may think about granularity

Comment: I just code the simple code. In my situation I protect only std::map and actually use ting::shared_mutex(std::shared_mutex). Thanks for answer!

Comment: Everything is possible, if you want to differentiate lock for write and lock for read with a `shared_timed_mutex`, you should drop the generic `operator->` in `mutex_map` and add two different acquire function and that return a different proxy doing the lock as you wants. Note that my example was only a showcase for the proxy idea.

Comment: Sorry but I think this answer is also great for me!